# Bash Script check word from in txt

Tags: bash

i need help in bash script 
I have a lic.txt at domain.com which contains the string "1234567".
i want to use string "1234567". in bash script 
if this word found in http://domain.com/license.txt run bash script function if not found output error license invalid how can i add this in my bash script

my bash script code is

```
if [ $1 ]; then
  SIZE=$(($1 * 1024))
else
  SIZE=$((100 * 1024))
fi
Sname=`echo $0 | sed 's/.\///g'`;

for x in $TXT_PATH/*_t.txt
do
if [ ! -e $LOCK_FILE ]; then

  if [ "$x" == "$Sname" ]; then
    echo -ne;
  elif [ -d "$x" ] || [ -e "$x" ]; then
      /bin/touch $LOCK_FILE
      My command 1
      My command 2
      My command 3
      My command 4
      My command 5
      My command 6
      My command 7
      rm -rf $LOCK_FILE
  fi
else
  echo "Lock file remove for run"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need something like that:

```
wget http://domain.com/license.txt
code = $(grep 1234567 license.txt)
if [ -z $code ]; then echo "Invalid license"; else function_call_here; fi
```

Thanks Fredrik

Comment: [UUoCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and don't use backticks, use `$(...)` instead